# How can I track an event accross multiple resources in gem5?

Tags: debugging, gem5

I would like to know if there is a proper method to track memory accesses 
across multiple resources at once. For example I set up a simple dual core CPU 
by advancing the simple.py from learning gem5 (I just added another 
TimingSimpleCPU and made the port connections).

I took a look at the different debug options and found for example the 
MemoryAccess flag (and others), but this seemed to only show the accesses at 
the DRAM or one other resource component.

Nevertheless I imagine a way to track events across CPU, bus and finally memory.
Does this feature already exist?

What can I try next? Is it and idea to add my own *--debug-flag* or can I work 
with the **TraceCPU** for my specified use?

I haven't worked much with gem5 yet so I'm not sure how to achieve this. Since until now I only ran in *SE* mode is the *FS* mode a solution?

Finally I also found the *TraceCPUData* flag in the --debug-flags, but running 
this with my config script created no output (like many other flags btw. ...).

It seems that this is a *--debug-flag* for the **TraceCPU**, what kind of output does this flag create and can it help me?

Comment: Hi Justin, I had seen [the message on the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17764.html) and was waiting to see if anyone had better answer since I don't have a perfect one, but I'll reply with some possibly useful indications in this comment for now. TraceCPU: this is a CPU that does not really simulate a CPU, but rather replays traces from other simulations. After a quick look, it does not seem mentioned in learning gem5 (I'd be surprised ot see it in an, are you sure that it is used?

Comment: About linking memory requests to instructions: I haven't yet learnt to do that amazingly yet. What does work without doubt but is a bit bit brutal is to `--debug-flags Exec` and go back the event tree until you reach other predecessors. Some interpretations of `Event` logs can be [seen here](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-event-queue). The reason I don't say this is amazing is that it is laborious to find out what each event represents since event names in that trace are mostly cryptic.

Comment: But you can guess a lot from the SimObject that gets printed in each line, and if you enable other traces, you can then understand more easily where each event comes from. E.g. once you see a CPU instruction log being logged together with an event, you know that the event is from that part of the CPU.

Comment: Each CPU type has its own debug flag, so you have to enable the right one, have a look at the `DPRINTF` tags of the CPU code of interest to enable that one specifically, e.g. `SimpleCPU` for `TimingSimpleCPU`. Then of course, from `--debug-help` you can see some obvious good candidate flags for the memory system, stuff like `CacheAll`, `Ruby`, `XBar` and `DRAM`. If you find debug flags that show some packet ID, then that should be the best way to backtrack memory requests, maybe it is already implemented. And if not, we should patch logs to show that.

Comment: FS will of course just complicate things since you will then have to deal with kernel stuff going on in addition to your userland one and the flags will be very similar (but more  for FS-only stuff you likely don't care about right now), I would just study the memory system in SE to start with. Another tip is to enable the `--debug-flag FmtFlag` which shows which debug flag generates each line of the log.